# Simple Edit check to email out person not working

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, triggers, getvalue

When someone puts a Y in a cell on a sheet it emails someone.

I am getting it no matter what I enter for the check: Y, F, T, bob - it ALWAYS emails out regardless of the value. It's like the `IF` is just setting whatever I am asking it to check to the value and doing it. Never seen this in the years of programming..

Can anyone see see something I am missing? I am using an edit trigger

```
function Checkchange() {

  var POs=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(11, 2).getValue(); 
  var rec=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(31, 2).getValue();
  var backorder=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(37,5).getValue();
  var buyer=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(38,2).getValue();
  var QA=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(41,5).getValue();

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(58, 3).setValue(POs)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(60, 3).setValue(rec)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(61, 3).setValue(backorder)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(62, 3).setValue(buyer)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(63, 3).setValue(QA)


  sendEmailsRec(); 
}

function sendEmailsRec() {
  var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
  var QAemailAddress = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(60, 1).getValue();
  var POs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(11, 2).getValue();
  var message = "Ready for receiving for PO " + POs;
  var QAcheckbox = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(31,2).getValue()  
  var subject = "Ready for receiving for PO" + POs;
  var check = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(60, 4).getValue() + QAcheckbox

 // if(QAcheckbox ="Y",MailApp.sendEmail(QAemailAddress, subject, message));
  if(QAcheckbox ==="hdjkheehehie",
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(60, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT)+
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(65, 3).setValue(QAemailAddress + subject + message)+
       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(60, 4).setValue(check));

    }
```

Comment: You might want to use the [edit] link below the question to at least tag which programming language / environment is involved. That will improve your chances tremendously of someone actually reading this who has an idea about the problem.

Comment: ok added in google sheet tag

Answer (score 0):

Your condition has a wrong logical operator. One `=` will always return `true`. Use `==` or `===` instead:

```
if (QAcheckbox == "Y"){
  MailApp.sendEmail(QAemailAddress, subject, message));// Always triggers regradless of value
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(63, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT));
}
```

You can read more about operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: thanks but when i changed to 2 or 3 same thing happens

Comment: if(QAcheckbox ==="Y",
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(60, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT)+
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(65, 3).setValue(QAemailAddress + subject + message)+
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(60, 4).setValue(check));
 
    }

Comment: Even though i put in say HEHEHEHEH and it returns HEHEHEHEH in the QAcheckbox still triggers

Comment: I just noticed you missed the brackets `{`. I updated the code in my answer. Since both `if` have the same conditions, you can join them in the same one.